# SQL - How to Stop MYSQL from command line

Tags: mysql, sql

I just noticed when I made an error statement, sometimes, it didn't stop or showed the error. Instead, the line kept going like this one

```
mysql > UPDATE person
      ->SET birth_data = sr_to_date('DEC-21-1980', '%b-%d-%y)
      ,>WHERE person_id = 1;
     ,>    
     ,> 
     ,>
     ,>
     ,>;
     ,>quit;
>
>
```

No matter how may times I try to enter quit; or exit, it didnt stop. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: You forgot a ' after %y

Comment: Yes, i forgot to add that, the question is, when i made an error like this, how do I quit and start the new line?

Answer (score 1):

If your question is how to "abort" the current command even when the current query hasn't been executed, or if you forgot a quotation mark, the answer is typing `\c`.

This will have clear the current command independently of what have you typed and start a new command.

Answer (score 0):

As you've missed a `'` sign, it assumes you're still completing a string and entering line feeds for the use in your query.

Simply close your `'` marks and you'll be allowed to quit.